# How to create a new list by adding a string to existing list without changing the existing list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list and a string as follows :

```
demo_list = [ 'rishi', 'john', 'mohan', 'sony' ]
demo_str = 'samsung'
```

I want to create a new list by inserting demo_str into demo_list without modifying demo_list. My expected output would be :

```
new_list = [ 'rishi', 'john', 'mohan', 'sony', 'samsung' ]
demo_list = [ 'rishi', 'john', 'mohan', 'sony' ]
```

Note that demo_list is as it is and a new_list is created by joining demo_list and demo_str. I can do this using 'append' but while doing so, demo_list gets modified. What I tried is as follows :

```
new_list = demo_list.append(demo_str)
```

However, it didn't work as append does not return anything also, demo_list gets modified which I don't want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how you can do this

```
new_list = demo_list + [demo_str]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `new_list = demo_list`, the objects `new_list` and `demo_list` point to the same list and modifying one effectively means modifying the other as they are essentially the same object.

You first need to create a copy of the list using the `copy()` method and then use `append` as:

```
demo_list = [ 'rishi', 'john', 'mohan', 'sony' ]
new_list = demo_list.copy()
new_list.append('samsung')
print(new_list)
```

Also, when you do `new_list = demo_list.append(demo_str)`, as `append()` works in place, the return value of the method is `None` so `new_list` gets assigned the value of `None`.